# Does circleci checkout pull the latest code from master or the code for the specific commit

Tags: git, circleci

Hello stackoverflow/circleci gods.

I have been using circleCI for a while now and I have a question about the 'checkout' step which I will do my best to explain. This is a snippet from my circleCI config file (I have a job 'a-job' whose first step is checkout):

```
a-job:
  docker:
    - image: docker-image-here
  steps:
    - checkout
    ...
```

My question is, does the circleci step 'checkout' pull the latest code from master or the code for the specific commit.

i.e. does checkout simply git clone master:latest or does it git clone SPECIFIC COMMIT HERE

Comment: plus one for 'stackoverflow/circleci gods.'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*disclaimer: Developer Evangelist at CircleCI*

VonC's answer is incorrect. In CircleCI 2.0 (which is what that config is), the "special step" `checkout` checks out the current commit. The current commit is the commit that initiated the CI run in the first place.

So whenever you `git push` to GitHub or Bitbucket, that commit gets built and that's the commit that the `checkout` step retrieves. In the case where you `git push` multiple commits at the same time, the most recent commit is the one a build will be started for.

Comment: Interesting. +1. So the filter branch I mention in my answer is to limit the scope of commits considered for build: if they are part of those mentioned branches, then the build proceed?

Comment: Exactly. You can limit them as a whitelist, a blacklist, or regex.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the [CircleCI checkout step](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#checkout) will checkout <del>the default branch of your remote repo (so usually master)</del>
Actually: the commit pushed (see [FelicianoTech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1195276/felicianotech)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50106998/6309)).

But you [can see here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/#branch-level-job-execution) that your yaml file can specify filter branches.
That way, you build only pushed commits which are part of specific branches:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  dev_stage_pre-prod:
    jobs:
      - test_dev:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - dev
                - /user-.*/
      - test_stage:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: stage
      - test_pre-prod:
          filters:
            branches:
              only: /pre-prod(?:-.+)?$/
```

As [mentioned here](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015659247-How-do-I-modify-the-checkout-step-):

> The checkout step is a convenient wrapper for a bash script that checks out your code. You can see the actual checkout code by expanding the Checkout code section of your job page on a previous job run.
>
> If you'd like to modify the checkout step, you can copy/paste this code from the job page directly into your config.yml or into a bash script using a [run ste](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#run)p.
> From here you can modify the checkout process to suit your needs. Remember to remove the convenience checkout step after adding your own custom run step checkout.